# RadAsyncUpload OnClientValidationFailed triggering for no reason

Tags: javascript, c#, telerik

Someone asked this question in [Telerik forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radasyncupload-onclientvalidationfailed-triggering-for-no-reason).

I have a RadAsyncUpload and the function for OnClientValidationFailed is getting called with a wrong file size error even though the file is well within the size limit.

**Markup**

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="fUploader" PostbackTriggers="btnSendEmail,btnSaveDraft" OnClientValidationFailed="fileUploadValidationFailed"></telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
```

**server side**

fUploader.TargetFolder = uploadPath;

fUploader.AllowedFileExtensions = New String() {"*.jpg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.jpeg", "*.bmp", "*.tiff", "*.pdf", "*.gpx", "*.tcx"}

fUploader.MaxFileSize = 2500000

**javascript**

```
function fileUploadValidationFailed(sender, args) {
var fileExtention = args.get_fileName().substring(args.get_fileName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1, args.get_fileName().length);
if (args.get_fileName().lastIndexOf('.') != -1) {//this checks if the extension is correct
    if (sender.get_allowedFileExtensions().indexOf(fileExtention.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
        alert("File type selected is not allowed.  Valid file types are .jpg, .png, .gif, .jpeg, .bmp, .tiff, .pdf, .gpx, .tcx");
    }
    else {
        alert("File too large.  Max file size 2 MB.");
    }
}
else {
    alert("File type selected is not allowed.  Valid file types are .jpg, .png, .gif, .jpeg, .bmp, .tiff, .pdf, .gpx, .tcx");
}}
```

**web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: See the demo:  https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/asyncupload/client-side-programming/onclientvalidationfailed

Answer (score 0):

Answer is telerik:RadAsyncUpload will not support  dot(.) and star(*)

See the example:  [AsyncUpload - File Upload via AJAX](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/imageeditor/examples/imageupload/defaultcs.aspx?product=asyncupload)

[image]